# How to set a background color in cell tempplate based on a condition, ng-grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-grid

I just tried to set a **background color** based on a value return from a function, I have tried **ng-style** and **ng-class**, Both are not suitable to call a function in my controller.

**Ng-Grid Cell Template**

```
 { field: 'IssueStatusID', displayName: 'Issue Status', cellTemplate: '<div ng-class=\"{keydataservice("Issuestatus",row.entity.IssueStatusID)}"><div class=\"ngCellText\"><span>{{keydataservice("Issuestatus",row.entity.IssueStatusID)}}<span><\div><\div>' },
```

**CSS**

```
.Red {
    background-color:red;
}
.Amber {
    background-color:aquamarine;
}
.Green {
    background-color:green;
}
```

Keydataservice is a function that returns a corresponding class name to include, But this is not working, I'm using ng-grid here,Please somebody help me through this,